# How to Get Multiple Outputs From Multiple User Inputs in Python (Invalid Literal Error)

Tags: python

Here is an extremely simple code:

```
walmart_prices = [0, 10, 15, 20, 12, 25]
costco_prices = [0, 5, 20, 15, 10, 12]
sprouts_prices = [0, 12, 8, 15, 20, 18]

store = input("Walmart, Costco, or Sprouts?").lower()

if store == ("walmart"):
    w_items = int(input("1 - $10, 2 - $15, 3 - $20, 4 - $12, 5 - $25"))
    print("Here are your items:", w_items)
    print("Total cost; $", walmart_prices[w_items])

if store == ("costco"):
    c_items = int(input("1 - $5, 2 - $20, 3 - $15, 4 - $10, 5 - $12"))
    print("Here are your items:", c_items)
    print("Total cost; $", costco_prices[c_items)])

if store == ("sprouts"):
    s_items = int(input("1 - $12, 2 - $8, 3 - $15, 4 - $20, 5 - $18"))
    print("Here are your items:", s_items)
    print("Total cost; $", sprouts_prices[s_items)])
```

When I go to enter multiple values in the items user input, it gives me an error "invalid literal for int() with base:

I was wondering what the solution to the problem was. I am new to Python so any help is great :)

Answer (score 0):

Well `int` will try to take whatever input you give it and turn that into a single number. Since it cannot do that for something like "1 2 3 1 4" or whatever, it will tell you that it can't turn that into a single integer. That's the error you get.

So what you need to do: Decide what sort of input you want to consider as valid, and then properly parse that. Like...

`inputs = input("blablabal").split(" ")`

This will take the user input from `input` and turn that into a *list* of inputs, by splitting the user input at the spaces.

And then you could turn each of those into ints, like

`w_items = [int(item) for item in inputs]`

Comment: I am very new to Python... could you tell me exactly what I need to change and where? Thanks

Comment: Replace your line that starts like w_items with the two lines I have in my answer. That should do it.